# C# LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

I have some data in a List of User defined types that contains the following data:

name, study, group, result, date.  Now I want to obtain the name, study and group and then a calculation based onthe result and date.  The calculation is effectively:

```
log(result).where max(date) minus log(result).where min(date)
```

There are only two dates for each name/study/group, so the result from the maximum data (log) minus the result from the minumum date (log).  here is what I have tried so far with no luck:

```
 var result = 
    from results in sortedData.AsEnumerable()
    group results by results.animal
    into grp
    select new
    {
         animal = results.animal,
         study = results.study,
         groupNumber = results.groupNumber,
         TGI = System.Math.Log(grp.Select(c => c.volume)
                                  .Where(grp.Max(c=>c.operationDate)))
             - System.Math.Log(grp.Select(c => c.volume)
                                  .Where(grp.Min(c => c.operationDate)))
    };
```

Anybody any pointers?  Thanks.

Comment: can you provide an example of what the input XML looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear how the grouping relates to your problem (what sense does it make to extract a property from a range variable *after* it has been grouped?), but the part you're having difficult with can be solved easily  with  [`MaxBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) and [`MinBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs?spec=svn158&r=93) operators, such as the ones that come with [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

```
var result = from results in sortedData.AsEnumerable()
             group results by results.animal into grp
             select new
             {
                animal = grp.Key,
                study = ??,
                groupNumber = ??,
                TGI  =  Math.Log(grp.MaxBy(c => c.operationDate).volume) 
                      - Math.Log(grp.MinBy(c => c.operationDate).volume)    
              };
```

Otherwise, you can simulate these operators with `Aggregate`, or if you don't mind the inefficiency of sorting:

```
var result = from results in sortedData.AsEnumerable()
             group results by results.animal into grp

             let sortedGrp = grp.OrderBy(c => c.operationDate)
                                .ToList()
             select new
             {
                animal = grp.Key,
                study = ??,
                groupNumber = ??,
                TGI  = sortedGrp.Last().volume  - sortedGrp.First().volume               
             };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax problems, you cannot use the results parameter after your *into grp* line. So my initial attempt would be to change your statement like so

```
var result = 
    from results in sortedData.AsEnumerable()
    group results by new
    {
     Animal = results.animal,
     Study = results.study,
     GroupNumber = results.groupNumber 
    }
    into grp
    select new
    {
         animal = grp.Key.Animal,
         study = grp.Key.Study,
         groupNumber = grp.Key.GroupNumber,
         TGI = System.Math.Log(grp.OrderByDescending(c=>c.operationDate).First().volume)

             - System.Math.Log(grp.OrderBy(c=>c.operationDate).First().volume)
    };
```

Comment: I realised after I had typed it....had left in some mishmash of early attempts :)  Thanks for the answer.